# Trouble initializing AngularJS Controller: Cannot set property ... of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and working on a small project which has multiple modules loaded onto a single page as requested. Currently I'm just trying to get the application to load a parameter with the staffdetails.html module and update it with the controller. Currently it just displays

Hello

Staff Details....

{{testing}}

So the value from the controller is not being loaded. I've tried in both angular 1.2 legacy and 1.5.9 (I think the latest stable), as I know syntax has apparently changed.

Here is the index.html page.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="lib/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <!-- load angular and angular route via CDN -->
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>1


    <script>
        (function() {
            angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]);
        }());
    </script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <!--script src="app/service/informationStorage-Service.js"</script-->

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="app/controller/additionalfeatures-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controller/outcome-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controller/staffdetails-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controller/training-controller.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready (
        function () {
            var app = angular.module("app");
            console.log("Index1");
            app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$compileProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {
                //$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
                $stateProvider.state(
                    "staffdetails", {
                        url: "/staffdetails",
                        views: {
                            "": {
                                templateUrl: "template/staffdetails.html",
                                controller: "StaffDetailCtrl"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            console.log("Index2");
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");
            } ]);
        } ());

    </script>
</head>
<body>
Hello
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
    <div id="main">
        <div ui-view ng-cloak></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

staffdetails-controller.js

```
(function() {
"use strict";
var app = angular.module("app");

app.controller('StaffDetailCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    console.log("StaffDetailCtrl");

    function saveDetails($scope) {

        $scope.testing = ["This is Working"];
    };

    saveDetails();
}]);

});
```

Finally the page which is being called as a module

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Staff Details...</p>
    <p> {{testing}} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You do not have an ng-app and ng-controller in your markup.

Comment: ng-app is in the html tag, is this the wrong place? where should ng-controller be called? Sorry very new to angular :)

Comment: `<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>1`. There is unnecessary 1 at the end. remove it.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, it didn't change the issue though.

Comment: the code in staffdetails-controller.js is not any IIFE. You would want to execute the function by adding () at the end before `);`.

Comment: You do not need the ng-controller with your ui-router. Your ng-app declaration is good.

Comment: See my answer below. You needed to pass $scope into saveDetails($scope); BTW this is an example of why you should NOT use the minified js during development. I used the full AngularJS and it showed me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not passing the $scope into your `saveDetails()` function.

I modified your code slightly so it would work here in a snippet. But, the main change was this line:

```
    saveDetails($scope);
```

See working snippet here:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="lib/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <!-- load angular and angular route via CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>



    <!-- Controllers -->

    <script>
        angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]);
        var app = angular.module("app");

        app.controller('StaffDetailCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log("StaffDetailCtrl");
            function saveDetails($scope) {
                $scope.testing = ["This is Working"];
            }

            saveDetails($scope);
        }]);

        console.log("Index1");
        app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$compileProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {
            //$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
            $stateProvider.state(
                    "staffdetails", {
                        url: "/staffdetails",
                        views: {
                            "": {
                                template: '<div class="container">' +
                                '<p>Staff Details...</p>' +
                                '<p> {{testing}} </p>' +
                                '</div>',
                                controller: "StaffDetailCtrl"
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
            console.log("Index2");
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/staffdetails");
        } ]);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
Hello
<!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
<div id="main">
    <div ui-view ng-cloak></div>
</div>
</body>
```